# How do i access an id from the link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I am displaying list of cities from the database ,each as a link.I want when a user click on any of the cities ,the action respond by grabbng the id of that city and re use it on the next action(show action in this case).So How do you grab an id from the link?Below is my idea which didnt work.Thank you in advance.

View/cities

```
    <%@cities.each do |city| %>
    <a href="/deal/city"><%=city.name%></a><br/>
    <%end%>
```

Controller

```
   Class DealController < ApplicationController
   def all_cities
   @cities=City.find(:all)
   end

   def city
   @city=City.find(params[:city_id]) 
   session[:city_id] = @city.id
   redirect_to :controller=>"deal",:action=>"show"
   end  

   def show
   unless session[:city_id].nil? || session[:city_id].blank?
   @city = City.find(session[:city_id])
   @deals=@city.deals
   end

   end
```

routes

```
    get "deal/city"
    match 'deal/city'  => "deal#city"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing the `city_id` in the link. Try:

```
<% @cities.each do |city| %>
    <a href="/deal/city?city_id=<%= city.id %>"><%= city.name %></a><br/>
<% end %>
```

If you want the link to be like "/deal/city/1" and get 1 as `params[:city_id]`, you can modify your routes like this:

```
match 'deal/city/:city_id'  => "deal#city", :via => :get
```

and use the link like this:

```
<% @cities.each do |city| %>
    <a href="/deal/city/<%= city.id %>"><%= city.name %></a><br/>
<% end %>
```

Comment: @katie...also in your code, I see `unless session[:city_id].nil? || session[:city_id].blank?`..actually `.blank?` checks for `nil` values(infact it checks for `nil`, `""`, `"  "`, `[]` and what not). So your code can be reduced to `unless session[:city_id].blank?` or using `.present?` which is the opposite of `.blank?`, `if session[:city_id].present?`(which is more readable IMHO)